# Nginx reverse proxy returns 404 on static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Basically I have two local application hosted on 2 different local port.

I'm trying to access `http://localhost/admin` which is serve via reverse_proxy but I got `http://localhost/admin/main.css` net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

Ive also tried below (without slash) but I still got the same error.

```
location /admin{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090
        ....
}
```

app1.conf

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/first_app/dist;
    index index.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/first_app.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/first_app.error.log;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
    location /admin/{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090/
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        client_max_body_size 0;
    }
    location ~* .(ico|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|css|swf|js|woff)$ {
        access_log off;
        gzip_static on;
        gzip_comp_level 5;
        expires 1M;
        #add_header Cache-Control private;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
}
```

app2.conf

```
server{
    listen 8090;
    listen [::]:8090;

    root /var/www/second_app/dist;

    location /{
          try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone can explain to me what I'd miss? Thanks much.

Comment: Try: `location ^~ /admin/`

Comment: When I use `location ^~ /admin/` it will redirect back to app 1 when I access `http://localhost/admin`

Comment: Did you found the solution?